# How can I select a specific XML node and fetch the values in its child nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to select a specific node and fetch the values in it's childnodes. This would normally be pretty easy, but the complication is that the nodes have the same name. My xml looks something like this;

```
<Settings>
  <Config>
  </Config>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <ID>Hello</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>True</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ID>Stack</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>False</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ID>Overflow</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>False</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Settings>
```

Each `<ID>`'s innertext is always unique. I now want to select the `<Item>` ,where it's `<ID>`'s innertext is "Stack". (I need the other childnode-values as well, like Pth, Zvb and Ico. So everything under `<Item>` basically)

I did this is powershell, and it looks something like this;

```
$script:specificItem = $dgvItems.rows[$_.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value
$script:fetch = @($xml.SelectNodes('//Item')) | Select-Object * | Where { $_.ID -like $specificItem }
```

So far I've got this (I'm in a RowEnter event of a datagridview):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(GlobalVars.configfile);

int rowindex = dgvItemlist.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
dgvItemlist.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); //This will contain for example "Stack"

XmlNodeList Items = xml.SelectNodes("//Items/Item"); //probably other ways to start as well
```

... but from here I struggle with filtering or selecting the one I want. I know this is a fairly common question, but I can't find a good solution for this exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use XDocument (Linq to XML):

```
string xml =@"<Settings>
  <Config>
  </Config>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <ID>Hello</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>True</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ID>Stack</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>False</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ID>Overflow</ID>
      <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
      <Zvb>False</Zvb>
      <Ico>True</Ico>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Settings>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement desired = xdoc.Descendants("Item").FirstOrDefault(x=>(string)x.Element("ID")=="Stack");
if(desired!=null)
{
    string Pth = (string)desired.Element("Pth");
    string Zvb = (string)desired.Element("Zvb");
    string Ico = (string)desired.Element("Ico");
}
```

`desired` will be the wanted element.

Comment: I will try this. It looks very promising. However, I need to load the xml file instead of "hardcoding" it into a string like that. Is that possible? I tried to replace the `string xml = @"...` with `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(GlobalVars.configfile);` - but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MadsTheMan To load a file would be the `Load` Method instead of `Parse`. Maybe your xml is not well formed? If Parse is working for you, you could try load the file to a string using File.ReadAllText and then use the Parse.

Comment: @MadsTheMan `GlobalVars.configfile` is the path to the file that contains the exact xml you posted? Because I just tested `Load` here and it worked.

Comment: Correct. Since it worked for you, it's probably some small errors here. I'll try a few things out. I did (just to be sure) switch out `GlobalVars.configfile` with `@"c:\path\to\file\config.xml` inside the load and still nothing happens, but I'll figure it out I think. Let's see...

Comment: @MadsTheMan Try `string deb = File.ReadAllText(GlobalVars.configfile)` and see the resulting string in the debugger.

Comment: Oh yea - now I see it. Apparently I had some typos in my code, my bad for sure. This code now works beautifully, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the answer and the help along the way!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the last line of your code into:

```
XmlNodeList Items = xml.SelectNodes("//Items/Item[ID='Stack']");
```

This should return:

```
<Item>
  <ID>Stack</ID>
  <Pth>Somevalue</Pth>
  <Zvb>False</Zvb>
  <Ico>True</Ico>
</Item>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Useful, I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It will return the specific node you are looking for.

```
XmlNode itemNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ID[text()='Stack']").ParentNode;
```